# Where is the 'holdout' option for collections in 2.8

Tags: masking

I want to ask about the holdout option for collections. In view layer menu I only have 2 options - set exclude and clear exclude, but nowhere I can find a holdout option. Maybe someone knows something about whether it was removed or maybe they changed its place?

Comment: Hi, welcome to Blender Stack Exchange! What did holdout do, exactly? And what do you mean by collections? Blender 2.8 has them, but as far as I know there wasn't anything called that before.

Comment: On many tutorials I see option called holdout - it work like mask in previous blender - for ex we have 2 collections with 2 boxes crossing each other(one for collection) and when we set one collection to holdout, it will work like mask layer in 2.7 where holdout will be transparent and everything hide by it to camera will be transparent. I see this option in tutorials but I dont have it in blender.

Comment: What render engine is the tutorial using? I know in Cycles there's a holdout material _node_, but it seems to just be black (unless it only shows up black in the viewport).

Answer (score 2):

I've been facing the problem too, the explanation is that holdout is only working with Cycles !

[image: Apply holdout on a collection for the desired view layer and it will act like the mask layer of 2.7.X]

Answer (score 1):

https://youtu.be/JpdmneLtlXQ
This video shows how to enable the holdout option and a few others.

[image]

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/161422)